# different SSLExeption for different Api version in android for https

Tags: android

My base url is **https://qrt.g-star.com**

this error on android version 4.4.4  : api 19

```
 java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

this error on android version 6.0.1  : api 23

```
jvax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
```

this error on android version 5.0.1  : api 21

```
statusjavax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

**but this is work on Samsung tablet  version  4.4.2 :api 19**